# Verbatim coloring but keep brackets

Tags: verbatim

**I have this code:**

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
    > \textcolor{names}{A}={\textcolor{numbers}{6},\textcolor{numbers}{75},\textcolor{numbers}{46}}
    > \textcolor{names}{B}={\textcolor{numbers}{8},\textcolor{numbers}{55},\textcolor{numbers}{64},\textcolor{numbers}{48}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

**Outputs:**

```
> A = 6,75,46
> B = 8,55,64,48
```

No brackets are preserved. How can this `commandchars=\\\{\}` be defined to still give me output with original brackets and syntax color.

---

Removing `[commandchars=\\\{\}]`,

**Outputs this instead:**

```
> \textcolor{names}{A}={\textcolor{numbers}{6},\textcolor{numbers}{75},\textcolor{numbers}{46}}
> \textcolor{names}{B}={\textcolor{numbers}{8},\textcolor{numbers}{55},\textcolor{numbers}{64},\textcolor{numbers}{48}}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragements

Comment: As samcarter says, plese post a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. We cannot do that with your sniplets and will have to make guesses, and those might not coincide with your document.

Comment: @Alix What you want is not achieavable, you want to use:`textcolor{color}` which uses `{color}` to capture the value of the color and then on` A={8 }` you need this verbatim and colored.  There are many other ways to use for this type of rendering. With your minimal explain what you trying to typeset, i.e. what are these lists `A = 6,75,46` are they long? What happens if you have 100s? What colors are you going to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use different characters to replace the braces delimiting arguments.

And also to use a less heavy markup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{names}{green!60!blue}
\colorlet{numbers}{red!80!blue}
\newcommand{\cna}[1]{\textcolor{names}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cnu}[1]{\textcolor{numbers}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\[\]]
> \cna[A]={\cnu[6],\cnu[75],\cnu[46]}
> \cna[B]={\cnu[8],\cnu[55],\cnu[64],\cnu[48]}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Don't indent verbatim environments, unless you really want the initial spaces.

[image]